# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/KafkaUtils

Tags: maven, apache-spark, spark-streaming, pom.xml, spark-streaming-kafka

I am using following pom.xml to build my project. When i run the resultant jar with spark submit it gives the following error.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/KafkaUtils

However if I include --packages "org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11:2.0.2" option , it runs as usual. I don't understand why do I have to provide this option when my dependency is included as part of pom.xml.

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    test.project
    ede-products-uis-spark-streaming
    jar
    1.0-SNAPSHOT
    ede-products-uis-spark-streaming

```
<properties>
    <spark.streaming.mainclass>test.project.spark.streaming.StreamReader
    </spark.streaming.mainclass>
    <scala.version>2.11.8</scala.version>
    <scala.major.minor.version>2.11</scala.major.minor.version>
    <spark.version>2.0.2</spark.version>
    <java.major.minor.version>1.8</java.major.minor.version>
    <libthrift.version>0.9.0</libthrift.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>scala-tools.org</id>
        <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>confluent</id>
        <url>http://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.major.minor.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_${scala.major.minor.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_${scala.major.minor.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_${scala.major.minor.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_${scala.major.minor.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play-json_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
        <artifactId>play-json_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-M1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.parboiled</groupId>
        <artifactId>parboiled-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
        <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
        <version>${libthrift.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
                <args>
                    <arg>-target:jvm-${java.major.minor.version}</arg>
                </args>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>ede-products-uis-spark-streaming</finalName>
                        <shadedArtifactAttached>false</shadedArtifactAttached>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <includes>
                                <include>*:*</include>
                            </includes>
                        </artifactSet>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>reference.conf</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.DontIncludeResourceTransformer">
                                <resource>log4j.properties</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>${spark.streaming.mainclass}</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <relocations>
                            <relocation>
                                <pattern>org.eclipse.jetty</pattern>
                                <shadedPattern>org.spark-project.jetty</shadedPattern>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>org.eclipse.jetty.**</include>
                                </includes>
                            </relocation>
                            <relocation>
                                <pattern>com.google.common</pattern>
                                <shadedPattern>org.spark-project.guava</shadedPattern>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>com/google/common/base/Absent*</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com/google/common/base/Function</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com/google/common/base/Optional*</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com/google/common/base/Present*</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com/google/common/base/Supplier</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </relocation>
                        </relocations>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <shadedArtifactAttached>false</shadedArtifactAttached>
                <artifactSet>
                    <includes>
                        <include>*:*</include>
                    </includes>
                </artifactSet>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>reference.conf</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.DontIncludeResourceTransformer">
                        <resource>log4j.properties</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>${spark.streaming.mainclass}</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
                <relocations>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>org.eclipse.jetty</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>org.spark-project.jetty</shadedPattern>
                        <includes>
                            <include>org.eclipse.jetty.**</include>
                        </includes>
                    </relocation>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>com.google.common</pattern>
                        <shadedPattern>org.spark-project.guava</shadedPattern>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>com/google/common/base/Absent*</exclude>
                            <exclude>com/google/common/base/Function</exclude>
                            <exclude>com/google/common/base/Optional*</exclude>
                            <exclude>com/google/common/base/Present*</exclude>
                            <exclude>com/google/common/base/Supplier</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </relocation>
                </relocations>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the "provided" tag from Spark Streaming Kafka, as it isn't available on the cluster:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_${scala.major.minor.version}</artifactId>
    <version>${spark.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

When you create your uber JAR, it'll package Kafka in there as well, making it available to the class loader at runtime.